# Angular 6 component not showing up

Tags: html, angular6

I just started learning Angular yesterday so I apologize if I'm missing something obvious, but I am trying to display a component on the app.component.html, however, it is not showing up.

TS file for the component I am trying to display:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ImageService } from '../shared/image.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'image-list',
  templateUrl: './image-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./image-list.component.css']
})
export class ImageListComponent implements OnInit {

  images: any[];

  constructor(private _imageService : ImageService ) { }

  searchImages(query : string)
  {
    return this._imageService.getImage(query).subscribe
    (
      data => console.log(data),
      error => console.log(error),
      () => console.log("Request Completed!")
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  } 
}
```

image-list.component.html :

```
<button>Find Images</button>
```

app.component.html :

```
<image-list></image-list>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

image.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { environment } from "../../environments/environment";
import { Http, Headers } from "@angular/http";
import { map, filter, scan } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class ImageService
{
    private query: string;
    private API_KEY: string = environment.API_KEY;
    private API_URL: string = environment.API_URL;
    private URL: string = this.API_URL + this.API_KEY + '&q=';

    constructor(private _http: Http) {

    }

    getImage(query)
    {
        return this._http.get(this.URL + this.query).pipe(
            map((res) => res.json));
    }
}
```

Comment: other things in app.component.html are showing? I've tested your code, i can see Find Images button

Comment: @firegloves other things do show up; however, as soon as I add the <image-list></image-list> tags, nothing is displayed

Comment: please post your app.module.ts

Comment: @firegloves I added the code

Answer (score 25):

I had a similar problem trying to use a component outside its module.
In this case, you have to export a component from your *.module.ts*:

```js
@NgModule({
  // …
  declarations: [ MyComponent ],
  exports: [ MyComponent ],
  // …
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to import your Component and your Service into your app.module.ts and then to declarations and to providers property

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ImageListComponent } from './image-list.component';
import { ImageService } from './image.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ImageListComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [ ImageService ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Adjust ImageListComponent path into the import statement.

Teorically when you generate a component with Angular CLI with a command like this:

```
ng generate component image-list
```

it should update your app.module.ts file for you.

To generate a service use

```
ng generate service image
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work. However, I believe the issue must have to do with injecting image.service.ts into image-list.component.ts, as when I remove the injection from the constructor, the component loads. I have added the code for image.service.ts

Comment: Have you generated image service with angular cli or manually?

Comment: Edited answer, if you will have other problems like that rename all of your ts classes, regenerate them with angular cli and then paste your old code into generated files

Comment: Unfortunately this solution is not working.! If anyone got solution please post it as answer.

Comment: I just had the same problem, and I was doing the (stupid) mistake of putting the component outside the <app-root> in index.html.

Answer (score 2):

check this one

in     **src/app/app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpClientModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

from this link: *https://malcoded.com/posts/why-angular-not-works/*

Comment: This is what worked for me! I didn't have the HttpClientModule in my imports but did have it in my service. Thanks! ETA: after I made this change, I had to run "npm cache verify" before it would work

Answer (score 1):

You may try the Angular tutorial from: https://angular.io/start . It shows how to render a custom Ansible component on the app.component.html page.

You just need to update the `app.module.ts` file. Assuming your component is named `ImageListComponent`:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router'; // add this line

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ImageListComponent } from './image-list/image-list.component'; // add this line

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ImageListComponent // add this line
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    // add the following 3 lines
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: ImageListComponent },
    ])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

First try this, without adding any custom services.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have nothing that triggers the API call on your method `searchImages` in `ImageComponent`. Having a click eventListener on the `<button>Find Images</button>` tag should do the trick.  Also register the `ImageComponent` and `ImageService` in your `app.module.ts` file.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that I was getting errors in the html, precisely in angular-generated components and it didn't compile.

For example, I had a component which was inputting `[data]="data"` in the component, but as the data on the moment of passing was `undefined`(i.e. simply not fetched yet), it has resulted in an NPE, or `TypeError: Can not read properties of undefined`.

Check out if you have
a) enforced the prefetched data you have with !, like `data!:string`. If yes - change it to `data?:string`, and fix wherever the problem appears with `*ngIf` somewhere above.

Good luck!